how to display values sent from the backend to frontend
As shown in the code posted below, i have a web-service wsSentinelhubEngineProcessor, and i want to display what the backend sends, i want to display the following in the forntend:
res.send({
    processAPIResCode:processAPIResults.resultCode, 
    processAPIContents:processAPIResults.contents, 
    processAPIPathToTIFF:processAPIPathToTIFF.fullPath, 
});

for the code posted in frontend section, the following log message displays undefined while there is values sent from the backend:
this.#msg = ({msg:verboseTag + 'postUserInputSettings().successful communication with the web-service /wsSentinelhubEngineProcessor.', 
    procAPIResCode: procAPIResCode,
    procAPIContents: procAPIContents,
    procAPIPathToTIFF: procAPIPathToTIFF,
});
        

please let me know how to fix this issue
frontend:
this.#wsSentinelhubEngineProcessor = new WSSentinelhubEngineProcessor(this.#clsDigitizationPolygonInteractionsInst);
    this.#wsSentinelhubEngineProcessor.setRequestOptionsParams(this.#ndviCompContextObj);
    
    this.#wsSentinelhubEngineProcessor.fetchNDVIsTIFF((procAPIResCode, procAPIContents, procAPIPathToTIFF) => {
        this.#msg = ({msg:verboseTag + 'postUserInputSettings().successful communication with the web-service /wsSentinelhubEngineProcessor.', 
            procAPIResCode: procAPIResCode,
            procAPIContents: procAPIContents,
            procAPIPathToTIFF: procAPIPathToTIFF,
        });
        console.log(this.#msg); //this message displays undefined  <<<<<<<<<<==========================
    })
    .then(res => {
        this.#msg = ({msg:verboseTag , response:res});
        console.log(this.#msg);// this log displays the contents sent from the backend <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<=============================
                    

webservice:
fetchNDVIsTIFF(onResult) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        const ws = endPointsURLs.VUE_NEWSWM_APP_LOCAL_HOST_3000.description + endPointsURLs.VUE_NEWSWM_APP_PATH.description + BackendWssConstants.CONST_WS_SENTINELHUB_ENGINE_NDVIS_TIFF.description;
        await fetch(ws, this.#requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(response => {
            resolve(response);
            onResult(response.processAPIResCode, response.processAPIContents, response.processAPIPathToTIFF);
        })
    });
    

retruned values from the backend:
res.send({
    processAPIResCode:processAPIResults.resultCode, 
    processAPIContents:processAPIResults.contents, 
    processAPIPathToTIFF:processAPIPathToTIFF.fullPath, 
});


i solved it by changing the code in web-service section to be as follows:
this.#wsSentinelhubEngineProcessor.fetchNDVIsTIFF(res => {
this.#msg = ({msg:verboseTag + 'postUserInputSettings().successful communication with the web-service /wsSentinelhubEngineProcessor.', 
    procAPIResCode: JSON.parse(res).processAPIResCode,
    procAPIContents: JSON.parse(res).processAPIContents,
    procAPIPathToTIFF: JSON.parse(res).processAPIPathToTIFF,
});
console.log(this.#msg);

